# "new" URL slug for state with null parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have a CRUD app with a state tree that looks roughly like this:

- `main`

  - `main.tasks` (state for listing existing tasks)

    - `main.tasks.task` (state for editing or creating a task, depending on whether an `id` parameter is passed in)

      - `main.tasks.task.step0` (these basically correspond to tabs in a "wizard")
      - `main.tasks.task.step1`
      - ... etc.

On the `main.tasks.task` state, I want to be able to define its URL and parameters such that I can have a link (`ui-sref`) to edit each `task` (e.g. `/tasks/1`), as well as a link for creating a new task (e.g. `/tasks/new`), without silly parameter overloading or state duplication.

The only ways I know of to do this is to pass in a magic string instead of a valid ID, or have a separate state tree (including duplicates of all substates) for each of the two scenarios (create vs. update). That's what I've done for other parts of the app that are simpler, but in this case because I have so many substates for this part, I really want to avoid duplication.

Any hints as to how best to do this?

Comment: why not checking the `$stateParams`, such that if its a number, then you load your data (for editing), and that if its a string of value `new`, you provide a new fresh form for creating?

Comment: That's basically what I've done (that's the "magic string" approach). I don't like it, but if there's no other way then that's probably the least-bad way I know.

Comment: I also ended up creating a couple of dummy states that simply provide the URL/parameters I want and redirect to the real state with the expected parameters using the new `redirectTo` property in 1.0.0-rc.1. I'll post an answer with an example when I get a chance.